# I build keyboard with icon or image in Button and I want to show it in TextFiled or TextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios8

My keyboard built in a `UIView` with a button inside and I want when I press the button 
the icon or image to show in a `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You question is not clear what you need

Comment: I want to Write icon or image in TextField or TextView.

Comment: There question is clear the issue is they don't seem to have done any research or attempt this themselves. Please make some attempt at doing this yourself then come back and ask the question sharing the code that you have used and the specific issue you are having without that code. Vote to close and -1

Comment: Please also be aware that none of your questions that you have asked so far have anything to do with the `xcode` IDE. Just because you are using `xcode` for development doesn't mean you should use the `xcode` tag. The `xcode` tag is reserved for issues related to `xcode` itself such as `"Why doesn't xcode load?"`. In most circumstances if you think you should add the `xcode` tag more than likely you shouldn't. I have removed this tag from your questions so it does clog up the tag.

Comment: I searched a lot and could not find an answer that solves it. 
I do not want to use Apple's keyboard , I build my own, only to have my application. Keyboard contain pictures or icons and i want to displayed into TextField or TextView.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? Please share code of the specific area where you are having trouble. We help with coding problems we don't write all the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloc image-view add image to the view and set the image-view to the text field property leftView/rightView

Example :

```
<textField>.leftView = <view>;
```

Comment: I try this                                                               textField.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"744.png"]];                                              But it's showing me the icon once, I want that I could add a few times just like the emoji keyboard TextField.